# Upload file to Redmine via its api

Tags: java, http, redmine, redmine-api

I would like to attach a file to an issue via the [redmine-api](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/rest_api#Attaching-files). However, if I run my method I receive an `Execution failed for task ...`

```java
private void uploadFileToDemoRedmine304651() {
    String plainCredentials = "TestTheAPI:Qwert5678";
    String base64Credentials = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(plainCredentials.getBytes()));
    String authorizationHeader = "Basic " + base64Credentials;

    try {
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(new URI("http://demo.redmine.org/uploads.json?filename=dummy.txt" ))
                .header("Authorization", authorizationHeader)
                .header("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
                .POST(BodyPublishers.ofFile(Paths.get(String.valueOf(getClass().getResource("/dummy.txt")))))
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newBuilder().build().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println(response.statusCode());
        System.out.println(response.body());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        System.out.println("Ye, it ain't working my man.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ups, not what you wanted huh?");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("DON'T INTERRUPT ME WHEN I'M SENDING");
    }
}
```

Since this topic is very new to me in Java I seek your help.

Can someone explain to me, what I'm doing wrong?

---

Stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task 'Main.main()' <36 internal lines>
Process 'command 'C:/Program Files/Amazon Corretto/jdk15.0.2_7/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 <101 internal lines>
```

Comment: Can you print the actual stacktrace?

Comment: @papaya I can, but it wasn't really helpful for me. Its only concerning internal calls so I can't really do much about it, can I?

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace, Instead of doing `System.out.println` please do `e.printStackTrace();` and update the questions.